# Flask: Trouble Accessing View (URL not found on server)

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to add another view to my Flask app.  My app/views.py looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app
from helpfulFunctions import *

def getRankingList():
    allPlayers = main()
    return allPlayers

def displayLimitedNumberOfPlayers(limit):
    allPlayers = main()
    allPlayers[0] = limitPlayers(allPlayers[0], limit)
    allPlayers[1] = limitPlayers(allPlayers[1], limit)
    return allPlayers

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    rankingList = getRankingList()
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', rankingList = rankingList)

@app.route("/top100")
def top100():
    rankingList = displayLimitedNumberOfPlayers(100)
    return render_template('top100.html', rankingList = rankingList)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tried to mimic how the Miguel Grinberg tutorial defines routes for `/` and for `/index`.  I've created a view called `top100.html` in my templates folder, where the "index.html" file also lives.  However, when I try to hit `localhost:5000/top100.html`, I get:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

So it seems like Flask doesn't think that URL has a view associated with it...but I'm not sure why.

Any idea?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: try `localhost:5000/top100`

Comment: or add html into your route @app.route("/top100.html")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no view `top100.html` in your code.You can do either of these

```
localhost:5000/top100
```

OR

change `@app.route("/top100")` to `@app.route("/top100.html")`

Answer (score 3):

The route (or url) is specified in the `@app.route()` definition, so you should visit `localhost:5000/top100`.

The render_template `top100.html` is only referenced internally within Flask to specify the template used. Really, this page could be named anything and does not have to be named in any similar way to the route...it just has to match the template file used to build the page served at that url.